# Special Pop Up View in iPhone SDK with UICollectionCells

Tags: iphone, ios, uiactionsheet, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've quite throughly looked around for the name of what type of `UIActionSheet` this is.

[image]

Or if it's even totally custom. With the cancel button there, it seems like it's a `UIActionSheet`, and the section above it is a `UICollectionView`. As much as building all of that custom sounds non-time consuming and rewarding, I would like to know if there is a library name in which I can call for to default this style of panel pop up. Thanks.

And if it does turn out to be something that needs to be custom made, how would I go about doing something like this? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [UIActivityViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController), new in iOS6.

Comment: I love how I can ask a question on here, and it can be answered in literally seconds after I post it. Thanks again!

Comment: That's not really a quick question - now you know what it is, why don't you hunt around for some tutorials, and ask new questions if you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

It's [UIActivityViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011976) introduced in ios 6.

You can find more new controls in this link : [MobileHIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)